# How do I change where the sell goes to?

Tags: php, coinbase-api, coinbase-php

I am using this:

```
$sell = new Sell([
    'bitcoinAmount' => (-1*$buyAmount)
]);
$client->createAccountSell($account, $sell);
```

But it is sending my money to my bank account and initiating a wire transfer. How can I make it so it sends the money to my USD Wallet?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this:

```
$sell = new Sell([
    'bitcoinAmount' => .002,
    'paymentMethodID' => $usdWalletID
]);
$client->createAccountSell($account, $sell);
```